# django task managements system

Tags: python, django

i search for good task management system on python-django, with projects, tickets, attachments and user access customization for projects.
Advise what to choose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ive used [django-projector](http://django-projector.org/). It has all the features you ask for, but ive found it to be slightly unreliable integrating with git.

For future reference, i find the best place to check for existing django projects is [Django Packages](http://www.djangopackages.com).

The comparision of project management tools is [here](http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/project-management/).

Answer (score 0):

I built a simple Task Management webapp named **Django Coleman**, using just Django Admin. Take a look at https://github.com/mrsarm/django-coleman

[image: Django Coleman]